# Concepts of height and dimention in Algebraic geometry

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I'm studying the first chapter of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry by myself and I found this book really hard for a beginner like me, but my advisor said to me that I had to study Algebraic Geometry by this book during my vacations. Then any part of the Hartshorne's book which I find very dry or superficial I search the same subject in another books or notes available online which are easier to read and have more exemples.

Then my question is where I can find more material of this concept of dimension and height explained in this page of Hartshorne's book:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hartshorne assumes a background in commutative algebra.  You could pick up a book in that.  Macdonald, Hilton/Staumbach, or Eisenbud are good in my opinion.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 these concepts are learned in commutative algebra?

Comment: The bits about the height of ideals, Krull dimension, and transcendence degrees are from commutative algebra.

Comment: @user42912 Since the proof is just a reference to commutative algebra books, I would hope so.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Thank you for your help

Comment: @PVAL It's true I didn't notice it, thanks

Comment: Hartshorne already gives you an answer: The books by Matsumura and Atiyah Macdonald.